# PHP: Proper boolean conditional argument for the return value of a function?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, boolean

I have written a function that returns data on success and false on failure.

I was wondering if this is considered a proper way of evaluating the return value in php.

```
function data(){
  if($all_is_good){
    return $data
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

$data = data(); //basically either a long series of strings or arrays

if(!$data){  //<-- this is the line I'm concerned about, is it safe to assume this?
   echo 'oh no, bad stuff happened';
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is fine, although alternatively, you could use `if($data === false) {`. This ensures that `$data` is actually `false`, considering `0` and `NULL` are also seen as `false`.

Comment: An empty string `""` also evaluates to false.

Answer (score 3):

It depends in what exactly `$data` is (both its type and its value). It makes sense both to leave it as-is (if the type of the value in `$data` is not certain) or make the check explicit (e.g. `$data == false` or `empty($data)`) if it's a known type. It's really dependent on the specific circumstances.

See [Converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Answer (score 1):

It is safe unless there is a valid value for `$data` that would evaluate to false. A long (i.e. nonempty) series of strings or arrays won't evaluate to false, but still it's a potential pitfall.

You might consider using a strict comparison: `if(data===False)`